# Page loads unnecessary queries Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, haml, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a weird problem, every page of my website that contains database queries loads some extra items. I've never had this problem before, tried to check all controllers but haven't found any problems. Here is an example of output when I load (or refresh) **home page**:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.0-p0), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/c/wines" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:30 -0400 (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by CatalogsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"wines"}
Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "wines"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering catalogs/show.html.haml within layouts/application (0.2ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."catalog_id" = ? [["catalog_id", 1]] (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1


Category Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."catalog_id" = 1 AND "categories"."open" = ? LIMIT ?  [["open", "t"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Category Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."catalog_id" = 1 AND "categories"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  CACHE Category Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."catalog_id" = 1 AND "categories"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  CACHE Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."catalog_id" = 1 AND "categories"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 AND "products"."open" = ? AND "products"."category_id" = 1  [["open", "t"]]
  Catalog Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 AND "products"."open" = ? AND "products"."category_id" = 2  [["open", "t"]]
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  Rendered catalogs/show.html.haml within layouts/application (142.7ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.haml (11.1ms)
  Catalog Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (23.7ms)
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (15.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 937ms (Views: 890.8ms | ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)


Started GET "/uploads/catalog/photo/1/hero-8.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Processing by StaticController#home as HTML
Started GET "/uploads/product/photo/4/pc_pistachio.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Started GET "/uploads/product/photo/7/pc_pistachio.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Started GET "/uploads/product/photo/1/pc_creame.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Started GET "/uploads/product/photo/10/pc_pistachio.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
  Rendering static/home.html.haml within layouts/application
  Catalog Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT ?  [["open", "t"], ["LIMIT", 6]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Product Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (1, 2)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2
  Product Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 2
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 3
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 3
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 2
  Rendered static/home.html.haml within layouts/application (95.0ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.haml (15.0ms)
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (19.9ms)
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (18.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 400ms (Views: 389.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Processing by StaticController#home as HTML
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:31 -0400
Processing by StaticController#home as HTML
  Rendering static/home.html.haml within layouts/application
Processing by StaticController#home as HTML
  Catalog Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT ?  [["open", "t"], ["LIMIT", 6]]
  Rendering static/home.html.haml within layouts/application
Processing by StaticController#home as HTML
  Catalog Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT ?  [["open", "t"], ["LIMIT", 6]]
  Rendering static/home.html.haml within layouts/application
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT ?  [["open", "t"], ["LIMIT", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Product Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering static/home.html.haml within layouts/application
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT ?  [["open", "t"], ["LIMIT", 6]]
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (1, 2)
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Product Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (1, 2)
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Product Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 2
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 3
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Product Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 2
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (1, 2)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (1, 2)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 2
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 3
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 3
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 3
  Catalog Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 3
  Product Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 3
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 2
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 2
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 3
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 2
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 2
  Rendered static/home.html.haml within layouts/application (206.4ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.haml (6.5ms)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 3
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 2
  Rendered static/home.html.haml within layouts/application (195.5ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered static/home.html.haml within layouts/application (246.3ms)
  Rendered static/home.html.haml within layouts/application (255.3ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.haml (0.0ms)
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (13.9ms)
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (9.7ms)
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (3.2ms)
  Catalog Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (3.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (14.3ms)
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (5.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (3.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (6.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 859ms (Views: 853.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)


Completed 200 OK in 802ms (Views: 795.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)


Completed 200 OK in 849ms (Views: 842.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 15:55:32 -0400
Processing by StaticController#home as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 858ms (Views: 851.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)


  Rendering static/home.html.haml within layouts/application
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT ?  [["open", "t"], ["LIMIT", 6]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Product Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (1, 2)
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2
  Product Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 2
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 3
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 3
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 2
  Rendered static/home.html.haml within layouts/application (58.7ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.haml (9.7ms)
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (16.9ms)
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (11.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 261ms (Views: 254.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
```

My Static controller:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @catalogs = Catalog.all.where(open: true).order('created_at ASC').limit(6)
    # @products = Product.all.includes(:catalog, :category).where(open: true).order('created_at DESC').take(8)
  end

  def about
    @catalogs = Catalog.all.where(open: true)
    @categories = Category.all.where(open: true)
    @products = Product.all.where(open: true)
  end

  def download_pdf
    send_file "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/docs/1_s.pdf", type: "application/pdf", x_sendfile: true
  end
end
```

Note: I have similar problems with other controllers

At the beginning I thought that it's a bag because I didn't add any new code. Please, let me know if you need more code from controllers. Thank you very much for your time and help.

**UPDATE**

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :prepare_meta_tags, if: "request.get?"

  def prepare_meta_tags(options={})
    site_name   = "Alvian Imports Inc."
    title       = "Alvain Imports Inc."
    description = "For many years, Alvian imports alcohol accross Florida state and now it's time to grow. Absolutly new team with new products that will be loved by everyone. We have an exclusive partnership with Ponche Caribe and we are starting to deliver our products to Texas, California, Mexico, and Columbia. Our goal is to make alcohol importation better and faster, so our team is working hard to deliver wonderful products to your closest stores."
    image       = options[:image] || "app/assets/images/brand/logo.png"
    current_url = request.url

    # Let's prepare a nice set of defaults
    defaults = {
      site:        site_name,
      title:       title,
      image:       image,
      description: description,
      keywords:    %w[food food processor food service food and drink f&b food industry food and beverage service food & beverage food processing industry food and beverage manager food and beverage industry food service jobs food beverage beverage industry food service companies f&b service food service worker food industry jobs food service industry food & drink food drink food and beverage management types of food service f&b industry food and beverage department import imports alvian alvianimports miami usa florida],
      twitter: {
        site_name: site_name,
        site: '@IncAlvian',
        card: 'The Beverage Company. Ponche Caribe Curacao Blue & Liquors Exclusive Distributor Florida - Texas - California - Colombia Distributor. Must be 21 +',
        description: description,
        image: image
      },
      og: {
        url: current_url,
        site_name: site_name,
        title: title,
        image: image,
        description: description,
        type: 'website'
      }
    }

    options.reverse_merge!(defaults)

    set_meta_tags options
  end
end
```

Application.html.haml code:

```
!!!
%html(lang="en-US" class="region--#{controller.controller_name}")
  %head
    = display_meta_tags
    %meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1")
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no", :name => "viewport"}/
    %meta{:content => "user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}/
    %meta{:content => "yes", :name => "apple-mobile-web-app-capable"}/
    %meta{:'http-equiv' => "X-UA-Compatible", :content => "IE=edge"}
    %meta{:name => "HandheldFriendly", :contnet => "true"}
    %meta{:name => "MobileOptimized", :content => "176"}
    = render 'application/favicon'
    %title #{content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'Alvian Imports'}
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = analytics_init if GoogleAnalytics.valid_tracker?
  %body(class = '#{controller.controller_name}')
    %div(class="application-wrapper")
      = render partial: 'shared/navbar'
      = content_tag :main, class: "layout layout-#{controller.action_name}" do
        = yield
      = render partial: 'shared/footer'
    - unless params[:nojs]
      = javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have 3 models: Catalog, Category, and Products.

Catalog model:

```
class Catalog < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
    has_many :categories, dependent: :delete_all
    has_many :products, :through => :categories, :source => :catalog, dependent: :delete_all

    # Important fields
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

    belongs_to :catalog, :foreign_key => 'catalog_id'
    has_many :products, dependent: :delete_all

    # Important fields
    validates_presence_of :name

    def self.active
      where(status: 1)
    end
end
```

Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
    belongs_to :catalog, :foreign_key => 'catalog_id'
    belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => 'category_id'

    # Important fields
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Expected output in the console:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 16:41:26 -0400
Processing by StaticController#home as HTML
  Rendering static/home.html.haml within layouts/application
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ? ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT ?  [["open", "t"], ["LIMIT", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 1 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 1
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" IN (1, 2)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2
  Product Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 2 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 2
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 3
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3
  Product Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."catalog_id" = 3 LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 6]]
  Catalog Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."id" = 3
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 2
  Rendered static/home.html.haml within layouts/application (44.4ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.haml (7.9ms)
  Catalog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.haml (15.8ms)
  CACHE Catalog Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs" WHERE "catalogs"."open" = ?  [["open", "t"]]
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (8.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 218ms (Views: 213.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
```

Home page HTML (HAML), however it has to be mentioned that I get similar problem with other pages that requires queries (for example catalog show pages):

```
= content_for :navbar_class, "navbar-dark"

%section(class="hero hero-homepage")
  %div(class="hh-container")
    %div(class="hh-carousel")
      - @catalogs.each do |catalog|
        %div(class="hhc-item")
          = link_to catalog, class: 'hhc-container' do
            %div(class="hhc-background" style="background-image: url(#{catalog.photo});")
            -# = image_tag(catalog.photo, lazy: true, class: "hhc-background")
            %div(class="hhc-caption")
              %h4(class="heading heading-1 is-light") #{catalog.name}
              - if !catalog.description.empty? 
                %p(class="text text-2 is-light is-transparent") #{truncate(catalog.description, :length => 112)}

%section(class="section")
  - @catalogs.each do |pc|
    - @products = Product.all.where(catalog_id: pc)
    %div(class="content")
      %div(class="header header-hr")
        %span
          %h4(class="heading heading-4") New #{pc.name}
        - if @products.count > 6
          %span
            = link_to "View all " + @products.count.to_s, pc, class: "link link-secondary link-arrow"
      %div(class="row")
        - if !@products.empty?
          - @products.includes(:catalog, :category).take(6).each do |p|
            %div(class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3")
              = link_to catalog_category_product_url(p.catalog, p.category, p), class: "block block-product" do
                = image_tag p.photo, alt: p.name, class: 'bp-photo', lazy: true
                %div(class="bp-desc")
                  %span
                    %h5(class="heading heading-5") #{p.name}
                  %span
                    %p(class="text text-3") 
                      %span.is-primary #{p.catalog.name} 
                      %span - #{p.category.name}
        - else
          %div(class="col-xs-12 is-centered")
            %h5(class="heading heading-5") Currently this list is empty.
```

UPDATE 3

Ok, I didn't understand the course of the problem but I decided to recreate the database:

`rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Fixed the problem..

Comment: Did you check any `before_action` or `after_action` in you controllers or application_controller? Also check intializers..

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I've updated my question so you can take a look at my `application_controller.rb`

Comment: Is that log snippet for a **single** page load? Because it has multiple `GET /` requests separated by time.

Comment: @anothermh correct sir, this is my `home page`. I get the similar output on any other pages, for example `show pages`

Comment: what about your home html?

Comment: Since there's so much noise in the log, I recommend that you edit the question to point out what you expect to see (and why) and what you don't expect to see (and why). Also include model scopes, associations, and callbacks.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I don't think that the `html` is a problem because I get similar problem on every page where I use queries. I checked my `application.html.haml` but didn't see any problems. Updated the question with `application.html.haml` code.

Comment: @anothermh ok, will do, one moment please

Answer (score 2):

A whole bunch of things and hard to help without actually running the code.

First of all, familiarize yourself with good practice in regards of naming things.
`@catalogs.each do |pc|` is a no-no and should be `@catalogs.each do |catalog|`.

`if !@products.empty?` and `@product.count`, those trigger two queries and my recommendation is to write the count into `@products_count` and replace that empty? with `@product_count > 0`

Use `scope` in the model to replace things like `.where(open: true)`

In `@products.includes(:catalog, :category)` you can remove the `catalog` because you already walk the products by catalog and can use `pc` (or as I recommended above: `catalog`) instead of `product.catalog`

If `catalog_category_product_url` doesn't use anything fancy but just the ids (e.g. `catalog/5/category/2/product/23`) then you can do `catalog_category_product_url(product.catalog_id, product.category_id, product)` to prevent a few extra queries (especially if you forgot to use eager loading or don't want to load a big chunk of data from the db).

Comment: Thank you very much, this information is highly valuable for me!

Comment: If the app is in production, there's either something like newrelic or simple rubygems that analyze your log files so you can find those slow pages more easily and concentrate on them.

Comment: I do use `gem bullet` to identify `n+1 queries` but it only works in `:development`. Also, my logs were taken from development and I don't have any problems in production. Thank you for the response!

Comment: bullet is a great one. For production logs this can be useful https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer
I recently forked a sql queries count gem so it separates cache queries as well. that was for a page with 3000+ sql queries that I got down to 90! https://github.com/TomK32/sql_queries_count

Comment: Thank you very much, will definitely try all of theses gems!